# python3 add_command doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm programming with Python,
but I wanted to make a text editor of mine with tkinter

so I watched a tutorial but it didn't work.
This is the code

```
from  tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

filename = None

def newFile():
    global filename
    filename = "Untitled"
    text.delete(0.0, END)

def saveFile():
    global filename
    t = text.get(0.0, END)
    f = open(filename, 'w')
    f.write(t)
    f.close()

def saveAs():
    f = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension='.txt')
    t = text.get(0.0, END)
    try:
        f.write(t.rstrip())
    except:
        showerror(title="Oops!", message="Error had been finded. Please try                 it again")

    def openFile():
        f = askopenfile(mode='f')
        t = f.read
        text.delete(0.0, END)
        text.insert(0.0, t)

root = Tk()
root.title("STE v.alpha")
root.minsize(width=400, height=400)
root.maxsize(width=400, height=400)

text = Text(root, width=400, height=400)
text.pack()

menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar)
filename.add_command(label="New", add_comand=newFile)
filename.add_command(label="Open", add_comand=openFile)
filename.add_command(label="Save As...", add_comand=saveAs)
filemenu.addsperator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Quit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(filemenu)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

But the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/superjoy/Desktop/programming/print/memojang.py", line 42, in     <module>
    filename.add_command(label="New", add_comand=newFile)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_command'
```

How do I fix this? What did add_command change too?

Answer (score 1):

You're creating `filemenu`:

```
filemenu = Menu(menubar)
```

But then using `filename` which is set to `None` at the top of the code you've posted, which is why it's being reported as type `NoneType`:

```
filename.add_command(label="New", add_comand=newFile)
filename.add_command(label="Open", add_comand=openFile)
```

Try renaming those `filename` entries to `filemenu`.

From the documentation, `add_command` also doesn't take an argument called `add_comand`, but it does take one called `command`

Comment: umm... still, it doesn't work. The error says _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-add_comand" maybe the add_command had changed

Comment: The bit at the end of my answer explains that the `add_command` function doesn't have an option called `add_comand`, and how it does have one called `command

Answer (score -1):

Too many typos & mistakes. I managed to fix them somehow...

```
1c1
< from  tkinter import *
---
> from tkinter import *
2a3
> from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile, askopenfile
5a7
> 
10a13
> 
17a21
> 
24c28,29
<         showerror(title="Oops!", message="Error had been finded. Please try                 it again")
---
>         showerror(title="Oops!", message="Error had been finded. Please try "
>                   "it again")
26,30c31,36
<     def openFile():
<         f = askopenfile(mode='f')
<         t = f.read
<         text.delete(0.0, END)
<         text.insert(0.0, t)
---
> 
> def openFile():
>     f = askopenfile(mode='f')
>     t = f.read
>     text.delete(0.0, END)
>     text.insert(0.0, t)
42,45c48,51
< filename.add_command(label="New", add_comand=newFile)
< filename.add_command(label="Open", add_comand=openFile)
< filename.add_command(label="Save As...", add_comand=saveAs)
< filemenu.addsperator()
---
> filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=newFile)
> filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=openFile)
> filemenu.add_command(label="Save As...", command=saveAs)
> filemenu.add_separator()
47c53
< menubar.add_cascade(filemenu)
---
> menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
```

Comment: So, how does the make the code work? Please elaborate on why the OP got the error and which one of your changes fixed it. Just posting a bunch of code isn't really helpful.

Comment: It is not just bunch of code. It is a structured way of telling you how you can fix the code via diff tool. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility )

Comment: and... what is via diff tool?

Comment: My point was that you are not explaining why you changed what you changed. Which of the mistakes is the OP's main issue?